# How to creating a new column in python using data from two separate columns of a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, sql-update, calculated-columns, pandasql

Need help in writing this SQL update statement in python using the pandas library.

```
UPDATE example_table
SET NEW_COLUMN = EXISITNG_COLUMN *2
WHERE SOME_OTHER_EXISTING_COLUMN IN ('Value1','Value2','Value3','Value4')
```

Just to clarify, I want to create a `NEW_COLUMN` which a multiplication of values in the `existing_column` belonging to `example_table` SQLtable/dataframe. The values of `NEW_COLUMN` don't update if the condition in the `where` clause is not met. This is important because I would want to multiply with a different number for a another set of values in where condition. Also, it important to know that I am checking the condition on `SOME_OTHER_EXISTING_COLUMN` in the same SQLtable/dataframe.

I tried the following in python, but somehow it did not work:

```
value_list = ['Value1','Value2','Value3','Value4']
example_table["NEW_COLUMN"] = pd.DataFrame.where( cond= example_table['SOME_OTHER_EXISTING_COLUMN'].isin(value_list), self= example_table['EXISITNG_COLUMN']*2)
```

Side note: `EXISITNG_COLUMN` is float, `SOME_OTHER_EXISTING_COLUMN` is `string`/`object` and `NEW_COLUMN` should be a `float` datatype.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try below syntax df['NEW_COLUMN']= df.apply(lambda x: x['EXISITNG_COLUMN ']*2 if x['SOME_OTHER_EXISTING_COLUMN '] == 'Value1' else 0, axis=1)

Comment: This is a fine code. However, if I try using .isin() , which is what I was asking in the question, then it throws AttributeError. Update to the question: else condition would require to keep the existing value if the new_column is formed. How will the else condition change in that case?

Answer (score 0):

```
record = {
    'Age': [21, 19, 20, 18, 17, 21],
    'Stream': ['Math', 'Commerce', 'Science', 'Math', 'Math', 'Science']}

# create a dataframe
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(record, columns=['Age', 'Stream'])

value_list = ['Math','Commerce','Value3','Value4']
dataframe["NEW_COLUMN"] = 2*dataframe['Age'].where(dataframe['Stream'].isin(value_list), 3*dataframe['Age'])

print(dataframe)
```

When your column is in your declared list, Age will be multiplied by 2, if not in list, it is multiplied by 3.